# What is the probability that the length of the yellowtail is more than 41 inches?

Tags: probability, statistics

**Original Question:**

1. In a survey conducted by the Big Creek State Marine Reserve in California,
   the length of various species of fish caught at two locations were recorded.
   Suppose the length of a yellowtail caught at the Santa Lucia Kelp Bed is normally distributed with mean 38 inches and standard deviation 2.9 inches.

   - Suppose 1 yellowtail is selected at random. What is the probability that
     the length of the yellowtail is more than 41 inches?
   - Suppose 32 yellowtail are selected at random. What is the probability
     that the sample mean length is greater than 41 inches?

Now from the question I can see that We are given: Mean = 38 and SD = 2.9.

From that This is All I can think of --> Z = (41-38)/2.9 = 1.03 = 1 - 0.84849 = 0.15151
Now IDK if **0.15151** is correct or not. So Can someone please help me figure out this question.

Thank you.

Comment: You should calculate with more decimal places $(41-38)/2.9=1.03448$. $\Phi(1.03448)=0.84954$ Therefore $1-\Phi(1.03448)=0.15046\approx 15.05\%$

Comment: **Ad b)**

The sample mean is distributed as $\overline X\sim \mathcal N\left(38,\frac{2.9^2}{32}\right)$

Therefore the equation is $P(\overline X \geq 41)=1-P(\overline X <41)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{41-38}{\frac{2.9}{\sqrt{32}}} \right)=1-\Phi(5.852)=1-1=0$ For $z>3$ you can assume that $\Phi(z)=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**a)** You're looking to find the probability that one yellowtail's length is greater than 41.  Since the data follows a normal distribution, you can determine this value via the `normalcdf()` function on your calculator or on a website.  You enter the mu (38), standard deviation (2.9), and 'above 41.'  It draws a normal distribution and finds the area under the distribution between 41 and positive infinity.

There are plenty of tutorials online on how to do this on your TI-84, or whatever calculator you use.  Just google how to do the normalcdf function on whatever calculator you use.

For example, if you find the area between -1.96 and 1.96 in the standard normal distribution curve (mu=0, stdev=1), I'd get about .95, which means 95% of the area under the curve is between -1.96 and 1.96.

I did this on [a normal distribution calculator](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/calculators/normal_dist.html) and got .1505 (15.05%).  So the probability that 1 yellowtail selected at random is longer than 41 inches is **15.05%.**

Your calculations are pretty much sound, but (41-38)/2.9 is not exactly 1.03 (it's slightly larger).  Close enough my by standards, but not totally right.

===

**b)**  The sample mean is distributed with a mean of mu (38), and a standard deviation of $\frac{\sigma}{sqrt n}$.  N is the sample size, 32.  So do the normalcdf with mu=38, and standard deviation=0.51265241636 (0.51265241636 is 2.9/{the root of 32})

Using this on [a normal distribution calculator](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/calculators/normal_dist.html), I got 0.  It's obviously greater than 0, but it's still really low.  I tried the [Casio calculator that has super high precision](http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1180573188), and got a whopping 2.429678289052420155163E-9 or ~.0000000002.

Comment: But b) is about the **sample mean**. Not every yellowtail must be greater than 41. Even if it would be the case you have to calculate $0.1505^{32}$

Comment: @callculus, no problem anymore.  Fixed it.

Comment: Nice that you fixed it.